# Download existing file in server root file system using HTML/JavaScript on a Lua/Luci Server

Tags: javascript, html, download

Let me preface by saying I have no idea of what I'm doing. I've inherited a system from a contractor that we hired to do a job. I'm not significantly familiar with web development, and I have no idea how the magic voodoo was configured or really works. If you're going to reply, be patient, and assume I don't know jack about what you're telling me - please don't leave anything "for the reader to figure out." I'm embedded by trade and would rather bang bits than develop back end code for a website.

Server is running on an embedded Linux platform (basis is OpenWRT). The core is Lua/Luci, but there's a plethora of HTM files that utilize both HTML and JavaScript.

What I want to do seems really, really straight forward, but I can't seem to make it work: There is a file in /etc that I want to be able to download from the server to the local machine. Needs to work with IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

I would have loved something like:

```
<a href="/etc/file">download</a>
```

But it doesn't work for files outside the subdirectory area that lua/luci knows about (i.e. I can't "../../../etc/file")

I've tried several different things, but the biggest issue is I can't seem to get the lua/luci stuff to recognize anything new in the same directory that contains some of the htm files, nor anything from the server's root directory (e.g. /etc/file). Usually what I do goes back to the home page or displays:

```
No page is registered at '/admin/talon/file'.
If this url belongs to an extension, make sure it is properly installed.
If the extension was recently installed, try removing the /tmp/luci-indexcache file.
```

(And yes, I clear the cache before I reload the page).

I'm OK with creating a symlink to the /etc/, but that hasn't been fruitful, either - mainly because I really don't know what kind of magic the lua service is doing to find the existing files.

I'd prefer for the solution to be in just HTML and JavaScript.

Yes, I've looked around for a basic solution, but either the questions want to do more than just download, or there's not enough information for me to figure out what is supposed to be done.

Please post a full solution, not just snippets.

Comment: being able to download any file from a server via http is a MASSIVE security vulnerability. any "decent" http server is going to restrict direct file access to things only inside the site's document root. if you want to download a file from /etc, then the easiest way is to just create a symlink inside the doc root pointing at that file, and configuring the webserver to follow symlinks outside the doc root. and if it's all the same filesystem, then a hardlink will work even better - no special configuration needed.

Comment: As I indicated above - I'm OK w/ a sym link. But your answer doesn't answer my question: where would I put the sym-link relative to where lua/luci expects the file to be. What would the <a href> be, as apparently it's relative to what lua/luci expects. And what other magic voodoo do I need to do in order for it to actually work. You must have missed reading the first sentence of my request. Anyone else want to give me a real answer?

Comment: you're dealing with a web site, basically. that means you have "web paths", which is what you enter into a url to access something on the server, and there's "filesystem paths", which is what the webserver deals with in the background, mapping web->filesystem. if you want your /etc/whatever file to be available via http, then you put your link into your system's document root, e.g. /home/sites/example.com/html/yourfile -> /etc/whatever

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out based on some other code within that same source. It worked on one page, but not another. Not sure why - just more sorcery. Had to work within the LUA scripting language to get to the file I wanted; HTML was straight forward. If I knew what the magic thing was to make it work, I'd post the actual solution, but I think the solution is somewhat unique to how the original developer put things together, so it wouldn't be useful to anyone else.